# How to detect keyboard events on hardware keyboard on iPhone (iOS)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, keyboard-events

I have an app with a login page that has three fields for three different random characters. When the user leaves the last field, the soft keyboard disappears and the user can touch a "login" button on screen.

When there is a hardware keyboard (bluetooth or physical) attached, I'd like to be able to hit "enter" on it. However because the user is not in a field, I can't see how to detect this key being pressed.

Would anyone have advice on which class handles key press events? Presumably there is a delegate that I can use to receive these but my searches through the SDK haven't found anything.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to accomplish this is to have a hidden extra (4th in your case) text field.  Make it 1x1 px in size and transparent.  Then make it the first responder when any of your other 3 text fields are not, and look for text change events in that hidden field to trigger your key input event.

You might also want to check the notification for a software keyboard appearing if you don't want it to stay visible as well.

Comment: Hey, do you have a code example of how that would work? Especially how I hide the keyboard for the hidden textfield.

Answer (score 15):

**For iOS 7.0 or later**, you can return UIKeyCommands for the keyCommands property from any UIResponder, such as UIViewController:

**Objective-C**

```
// In a view or view controller subclass:
- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder
{
    return YES;
}

- (NSArray *)keyCommands
{
    return @[ [UIKeyCommand keyCommandWithInput:@"\r" modifierFlags:0 action:@selector(enterPressed)] ];
}

- (void)enterPressed
{
    NSLog(@"Enter pressed");
}
```

**Swift**

```swift
// In a UIView/UIViewController subclass:
override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool {
    true
}

override var keyCommands: [UIKeyCommand]? {
    return [ UIKeyCommand(input: "\r", modifierFlags: [], action: #selector(enterPressed)) ]
}

@objc func enterPressed() {
    print("Enter pressed")
}
```

Comment: This will override any other text input fields.

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to get the event type?  keyUp keyDown?

Comment: see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61312598/7487013

Answer (score 1):

As a followup to the response by @Patrick, here is how you do it in Xamarin.iOS:

```
public override bool CanBecomeFirstResponder
{
    get { return true; }
}

public override UIKeyCommand[] KeyCommands
{
    get
    {
         return new[]{ UIKeyCommand.Create((NSString)"\r", (UIKeyModifierFlags)0, new ObjCRuntime.Selector("enterPressed")) };
    }
}

[Export("enterPressed")]
private void OnEnterPressed()
{
    // Handle Enter Key
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind this will override any other text inputs on the app.